# Android google signin : adding configuration json file

Tags: android, google-signin

I have followed this [documentation](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-googlesignin-integrating) to add google sign in functionality to my app.

It works well on my device but throws an error when attempted on a separate device with a different account. I am assuming I will need to create another SHA1-key for that device and add it to the file.

If that is the case then how will this work once I release the app to the playstore for anyone to download/use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to actually add another configuration file everytime, you just need to add the SHA Keys of the device that is building the app.

As for coming to release on Play Store. When you sign and release the APK on Play Store, a new set of keys gets generated.

You can then paste these keys at your Firebase or Google console and you should be good to go. I would suggest you read up further on this topic.

[image: Here is an example]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @che10